# What is RecordType.DeveloperName named in the filter of a page layout?

Tags: page-layout, record-type, filters

I want to add a filter to a page layout that is based on the recordtype. I want to use the DeveloperName, of course. But when I try to do this, this is the choice of fields that I get:

[image]

Name or Record Type Name: which of these is DeveloperName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Record Type Name` is a **DeveloperName**.
You can see the attached screenshot for the same.
[image]

The `Name` is the label of the record type.